# Is there any difference between Random Walk with Walk Forward?

Tags: quantitative-finance, back-testing

Usually when we are looking for a continuous way to backtest our own strategy we see how to generate data using Random Walk and using Brownian Motion, but the question is not clear to me since for me both Random Walk and Walk Forward sound the same thing, besides the fact they way that the data was generated, am I correct on this assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Random Walk is a way to generate data, and Walk Forward is a testing method. For example, you can create a random walk model. But you cannot test a model using random walk. You can test a model using a walk forward approach.
Random walk is a model. A random walk model is a model where data is a random walk.
There are many ways to test a model. One of them is the walk forward.

Comment: That's clear as a crystal, thanks @Fan Zuki!